# Dynamically resizing images using MediaQuery in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have two pictures of different dimensions meant to be rendered as per the screen size of the phone the app is being run on which I suppose is something that can be achieved using MediaQuery in the following way:

```
if(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height < initialSize) {
  return Image.asset('Image meant for smaller screens')
} else {
  return Image.asset('Image meant for bigger screens')
}
```

What I don't understand is what initialSize value I should be putting in to check and resize accordingly? Hope I have been able to make my question clear!

Comment: How do you get `initialSize`? From any package?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh If you had to resize and render images on different screen sizes, how would you have done it?

Comment: I prefer using `LayoutBuilder` as parent widget. Also, can be use `MediaQuery`

Comment: Can you maybe post snippets to demonstrate how this can be done using MediaQuery and LayoutBuilder? @YeasinSheikh

Comment: You like to set two different images based on screen height?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Apologies for the late reply. Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 0):

`initialSize` differentiate the small image and large image screen based on screen height.

Let say if device's height is less than 200px we want to show X image, else show Y image.

```dart
  Image getImage() {
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height < 200) {
      return Image.asset('Image meant for smaller screens');
    } else {
      return Image.asset('Image meant for bigger screens');
    }
  }
```

You need to choose how you like to define small and large screen image, like here `200`, `initialSize`.

Comment: So I can set the size with any random value right?

Comment: Yes, you can do that; You can also search for `size for responsive design`

Comment: How can we search for size for responsive design?